# My Delphi 11.1 debugger has suddenly become very sluggish on x64 projects; was ok a week or so ago. Any ideas as to cause?

Tags: performance, debugging, delphi

**UPDATE: Unplugging network (cable and wifi) causes (nearly?) normal debug speed to return.  Have tried diabling firewall no change.  But no network restores normal service**

**UPDATE 2:  Slowness is across all windows x64 builds, not just the single large project.  If I build and debug the 32 bit windows target speed is normal (F8 is instant)**

Others in the office have seen it also.  Stepping over code with F8 is now taking between 5 and 15 seconds for even trivial looking code blocks, eg this line takes 13 seconds to step over:

```
radius :=  Max(
 Max( 1.001*vMod( vSum( v1, v2) ), m_testRadius), 
 0.01);
```

A week ago stepping over this was more or less instant, now 13 seconds. Adding a watch or evaluate modify takes about 5 seconds.

Interestingly, if I add a breakpoint on the next line and F9, it only takes 2 sec to step over it.. still a little slow but not unreasonable.

The debugged application is running normally when its running.

1. We have tried rolling our code back to checkpoints a month ago in
   cased we introduced something odd- no change, still slow.
2. Have tried different delphi versions: 10.4, 11.1 update 1 and 11.2: no change,
   still slow.
3. Have disabled our antivirus, and uninstalled the ninjaRM software our IT company
   manage our pcs with: no change, still slow.
4. Have looked for recent windows updates that might be the cuplrit...
   nothing obvious
5. I applied all updates I can find to my machine, including Windows 11
   22H2 feature update... no change.  (One of my colleagues experiencing
   same issue is running Win 10 so doesn't seem to be OS specific)

Other smaller projects however continue to behave normally, just this one which is our biggest that has suddenly "hit the wall".

At this point debugging on this project is practically unusable :(  The prospect of porting a million lines of code to C# is not something we are hoping to avoid, but if we can't debug...

Its got us mystified: its across all our machines, its confined to a single project, its seems to have started recently, but if we go back to earlier source its still happening.

What are we missing? Has there been some bad windows update rolled out affecting win10 and win11 machines lately?

Thanks for any advice,
Chris

Comment: How similar are your machines? Windows does install BIOS updates (in Windows 11 often listed as Driver Updates, XXXX - Firmware) and other updates that might cause the same issue on a batch of similar systems that can't be rolled back. Could try on a dissimilar standalone system to check. Still odd that it effects debugging for only one project.

Comment: Have you tried using SysInternals SystemMonitor by Microsoft to check whether there is any unusual disk or registry activity when stepping through code in the debugger?

Comment: No network = instant fail for attempted network communications. Working network = if other side can't be reached then long waits for timeouts. Sysinternals TCPView or other network monitoring tools might help and see what it is trying to contact.

Comment: @Brian, it turned out to be all x64 projects, and the bigger the slower.  We have two main projects, one of which is always 32 bit so hadn't noticed it there.  But I saw the slowdown in some other little x64 projects also.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue when debugging a 32 bit application. And sometimes it works fine. Sometimes jumping to the next line of code using F8 takes about 5 seconds.. Moreover, this problem exists in Delphi 10.x as well.

Comment: Had the same problem since this week, but while debugging a large x32 application in 10.4. Stopping the service 'HitmanPro.Alert service' instantly solved this. (Using a local admin account). Now the service startup type is 'manual' so it stays off.

Answer (score 4):

Found the culprit:  **Sophos Hitman Pro Alert Service**  !!!

[image]

Disabling Sophos realtime from the local console had no effect, but disabling tamper protection did at least allow me to kill this service, and once this was gone, normal service resumed!!!

We are logging it with our IT provider who will hopefully pass it on to Sophos.  Strange that it affected x64 builds only, or at least much more drastically.

Comment: The reason why only x64 builds are affected is the fact that Delphi communicates with 64 bit debugger through network connection. It seems that Sophos doesn't like the protocol that is being used for this communication pretty well. This is then causing slowdowns. You could try adding Delhi to Ignore list so that Sophos won't be monitoring any network communication from Delphi.

Comment: Better add Del**p**hi, not [Delhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delhi).