# Delphi IdTCPClient.connect Hanging while threaded

Tags: delphi, freeze, indy

I am trying to run 8 threads making IdTCPClient repeatedly scanning a range of IP. When these threads are running, the main form is hanging, lagging. The "IdTCClient.connect" is the issue. Is there a way to fix that ?

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TTcpThread = class(TThread)
    Idx: word;
     procedure Execute; override;
  end;

  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;
var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation
uses IdTCPClient;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TTcpThread.Execute;
begin
  for var i := Idx*8 to (Idx*8) + (8-1) do  // 8 IP per Thread
  begin
    var TCP := TidTCPClient.Create(nil);
    TCP.Host :=  '192.168.1.' + i.ToString;;
    TCP.Port := 9999;
    TCP.ConnectTimeout := 500;
    TCP.ReadTimeout := 1000;
    try
      TCP.Connect;
      TCP.Disconnect;
    except end;
    TCP.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  for var i := 0 to 32-1 do  // 32 Threads
  begin
    var Thread := TTcpThread.Create(True);
    Thread.Idx := i;
    Thread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
    Thread.Start;
  end;
end;

end.
```

The mainform will freeze/lag while the threads are running

Comment: There is no possible way that creating and connecting a `TIdTCPClient` solely in a worker thread will cause the main thread to hang/lag. Something else is going on in your main thread that you are not accounting for. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I've changed the example as requested. This is functional and freezing.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is just no way for that updated example to freeze the main UI thread, as you are claiming. Your worker threads are not touching the main thread at all. And your main thread is not waiting on the worker threads. So, this does not satisfy the *reproducible* requirement of a [mcve]

Comment: All synchro has been removed on purpose, still, the app Freeze. That is exactly my issue. Please test it and you will see. (Alexandria 11)...

Comment: Are you running the application with debugging? That is the only scenario where you can have lags as IDE will have trouble handling that many threads.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar there is only 32 threads. The IDE will not have trouble with that many.  Esides, you can always reduce the number of threads for testing, or just freeze running threads in the IDE if needed.

Comment: "*All synchro has been removed on purpose*" - that is a MAJOR detail to leave out. *Any* synchronization with the main thread is going to block the main thread until the sync is finished, and if you do something wrong and cause a deadlock then you are going to freeze up the app. Please update your question to show EXACTLY what you are actually doing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Unfortunately, IDE does have a problem with that many threads during debugging (32bit). I have 8 cores 16 logical processors. As soon as I have more than 9 threads running IDE starts to be sluggish. The more I add the worse it gets. When I get to 16 threads it needs seconds to react to anything. With 32 threads running it is as good as dead.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I hope you have reported that to Embarcadero.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Not yet. It seems like this is the case for quite some time as even XE4 has similar issues, though newer versions definitely suffer more from this problem. I have to investigate further.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I found this issue is already reported as https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-38680 though the attached project does not show the issue that clearly as threads just sleep.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74553681/